# How to filter a queryset to show unique items of certain category in a database using django?

Tags: django

In my database for a website I am making to learn django, there objects each with a state, I want to be able to a page with a list of the unique states. I have tried using distinct but I get a "DISTINCT ON fields is not supported by this database backend" error.

My code at the moment just displays a list of all the states.

Is there a simple way of doing this / getting around this problem?

Thanks

The code which works but shows all of the states

models.py

```
class TowerSite(models.Model):
    siteName = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    siteState = models.CharField(max_length=2)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.siteName + ', ' + self.siteState
```

views.py

```
class StateList(ListView):
  model = TowerSite
  template_name="towers_states.html"
  queryset = TowerSite.objects.all()
```

html

```
<ul>
    {% for item in object_list %}
    <li>{{ item.siteState }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

When I try with `queryset = TowerSite.objects.all().distinct('siteState')` I get the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The distinct method in Django does not support field names for all database backends. It’s only supported by PostgreSQL. If you’re using a different database like SQLite or MySQL, you’ll get the error you’re seeing.

However, you can achieve the same result by using Python’s built-in functions. Here’s how you can modify your `views.py` to get a list of unique `siteState`:

```
class StateList(ListView):
    model = TowerSite
    template_name="towers_states.html"
    
    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = TowerSite.objects.all()
        unique_states = set(queryset.values_list('siteState', flat=True))
        return unique_states
```

In this code, `values_list` returns a QuerySet that returns tuples when used as an iterable, with each tuple containing the value for the specified field. If you only pass in a single field, you can also pass in the `flat` parameter. If `True`, this means the returned results are single values, rather than one-tuples. Then we convert this list to a set, which automatically removes duplicates because sets only allow unique elements.

Please note that this will perform the deduplication in Python (not in the database), so if you have a very large number of states, it might be inefficient. If you’re using PostgreSQL as your database, you can use the `distinct` function with a field name. If you’re using a different database and have performance issues, you might need to use raw SQL queries.

Comment: Thanks, I tried something like that but couldn't get it to work but working fine now, how large is considered a large database, this website would be theoretically only 100-200, but I guess knowing about different databases will be useful in the long run anyway